# How to allow for my app to be usable on all IOS devices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am in the process of making my first IOS application using Xcode 11.4. The idea for the app is very simple as I am still very much so in the learning phase. Basically the concept is that the blocks of ice disappear at random and then reappear when they are clicked, the objective being to  click the blocks that have disappeared before the time runs out and more blocks disappearing with each successive level. I have included the image below of the storyboard for clarity. [Story Board picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXF8Y.png)
The app works when I run it using an iphone 11 pro max simulator, however my issue is that it does not fit on the screen of smaller devices. Since all of the blocks of ice are images, I tried adding a variety of constraints in order to make them fit however none of these worked with my images getting distorted and often appearing out of the view. I am unsure on how to properly add constraints or if this is even the proper way to proceed, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be really helpful for others if you attached your code with your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use 'Vary for traits' xCode tool to design app for different width/height ratio.
Please see image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also change constraints constant's programmatically based on device settings

1 Create 'Device' struct that will detect your current device

```
struct Device {
static let IS_IPAD             = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad
static let IS_IPHONE           = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
static let IS_RETINA           = UIScreen.main.scale >= 2.0

static let SCREEN_WIDTH        = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
static let SCREEN_HEIGHT       = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH   = Int( max(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )
static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH   = Int( min(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )

static let IS_IPHONE_4              = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH <= 480 // 2, 3, 3GS, 4, 4S
static let IS_IPHONE_5              = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568 // 5, 5S, 5C, SE
static let IS_IPHONE_6              = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667 // 6, 6S, 7, 8
static let IS_IPHONE_6P             = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736 // 6+, 6S+, 7+, 8+
static let IS_IPHONE_XS             = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 812 // X, XS, 11 Pro
static let IS_IPHONE_XS_MAX         = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 896 // XR, XS Max, 11, 11 Pro Max
static let IS_IPAD_PRO_11           = IS_IPAD && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1024 // iPad Pro 11"
static let IS_IPAD_PRO_13           = IS_IPAD && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1366 // iPad Pro 12.9"
}
```

2 Create IBOutlet for your constraint

```
@IBOutlet private weak var myConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

3 Set constraint.constant programmatically based on current device

```
if Device.isIphone5 {
    myConstraint.constant = 10 
}
```